# How to Select & checkmark the row after load in UITableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a selection that will select just 1 row of category.
but I will like it to select Spirits row when loaded.

Something like this:

[image]

At the moment it comes to this without selecting anything:

[image]

Where shall I do the compare for the in order for it to `selectRowAtIndexPath`?

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    categoryString = [arrayCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = categoryString;
    if (cell.textLabel.text == categoryString) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell* newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    int newRow = [indexPath row];
    int oldRow = (lastIndexPath != nil) ? [lastIndexPath row] : -1;

    if(newRow != oldRow)
    {
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        newCell.highlighted =YES;
        UITableViewCell* oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath];
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        lastIndexPath = indexPath;
        oldCell.highlighted = NO;

    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: you have to reload data after assigning it the accessoryType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:** method to select a row programatically.

Few things to correct in your code. You should use `isEqualToString:` method to match the strings, like this, `if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:categoryString]) {`. Next thing is, you are assigning the `categoryString` to `cell.textLabel.text`, and on the next line you are matching them, so it would always return `YES`. I think you are matching the wrong values.

Comment: where shall i add the selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: ?

Comment: You can call this method anywhere you want to move table to a particular row.

Comment: Hi Empty,i wanna match the category string with the row, so i could select the correct row. may know how i can be done ? it will be good if there is a sample code thanks :)

i'm running this code but all rows are selected 
if (cell.textLabel.text == categoryString) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried the method matching the value with this. if ([categoryString isEqualToString:editValue]) {
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
 }
 else {
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

 }

it works but the checkmarks stayed there.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually set multiple check marks. for that you can use UIImageview for each UITableViewCell and as per the stored old data, you have to set check marks in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**(delegate method of UITableView).